# How to get all records from one table and only records from joined table with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

it seems like I've accomplished this before, but struggling again.  Here is my data:

```
tblHotlist
----------
ID
hotlistStatus
buildNumber
loadType
etc

tblessr
-------
ID
esHeadline
notesStatus
actionItems
bugStatusID
etc

tblBugStatus (not needed in query)
------------
ID
bugStatus
etc

tbl_j_hlbug
-----------
esID
hotlistID
timestamp
```

I want all the records from tblHotlist and if records exist in tblESSR, I need those where bugStatusID=300.  I've tried several different joins and subqueries, but still can't get the results I need.  Once I put the qualifier of bugStatusID=300, I only get the records from tblHotlist where records from tblESSR has a bugStatusID of 300.

failed attempt:

```
SELECT hl.hotlistID, hl.buildnumber, es.ID, es.notesStatus, es.actionItems
FROM tblhotList hl
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_j_hlbug j ON j.hotlistID = hl.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblESSR es ON j.esrID = es.id
WHERE hl.hotlistStatusID=100 AND hl.loadType='su' AND es.bugStatusID=300
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried different joins and a couple of subqueries, but I always get the same result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to move the limiting criteria to the joins or also look for null values.

```
WHERE hl.hotlistStatusID=100 AND hl.loadType='su' AND 
(es.bugStatusID=300 or es.bugStatusID is null)
```

When the outer joins occur, you have to consider null values will exist on records that don't have matching data.  As such if you try to limit by these, you will end up excluding the nulls w/o matching data; thereby negating the outer join.  Sometimes this is what you want... sometimes it isn't.  In this case I think you wanted the nulls and 300.

```
SELECT hl.hotlistID, hl.buildnumber, es.ID, es.notesStatus, es.actionItems
FROM tblhotList hl
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_j_hlbug j ON j.hotlistID = hl.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblESSR es 
        ON j.esrID = es.id
       AND es.bugStatusID=300
WHERE hl.hotlistStatusID=100 AND hl.loadType='su'
```

the Hl where clause doesn't matter as you're getting all records to begin with.

Comment: xQbert, thank you very much.  I had no idea you could qualify on the join!  The previous offering didn't work when I tried because (I think) bugstatusID would never be NULL, you would just not have any records in the join table associated, so it is an empty set.  I ran the query with that, but still got the same results as before.  Thanks all!

Comment: It should have worked as well.  Empty set in database terms of table joins results in a null value in each field returned.    It somewhat bothers me that the first option didn't work.  Think of qualifications on the join as occurring before the join.  not only would it reduce the overhead of the carteasean, but it also ensures you don't exclude records on outer joins.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the join, some of your result set BEFORE the WHERE will have NULL in bugStatusID, so you need to add this into your where if you wish to see those results as well.

```
SELECT hl.hotlistID, hl.buildnumber, es.ID, es.notesStatus, es.actionItems
FROM tblhotList hl
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_j_hlbug j ON j.hotlistID = hl.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN tblESSR es ON j.esrID = es.id
WHERE hl.hotlistStatusID=100 AND hl.loadType='su' AND (es.bugStatusID=300  OR es.bugStatusID IS NULL)
```